# Use a mixin named parameter in LESS as a pseudo selector

Tags: less, less-mixins

My idea here is to create a LESS mixin that could add a pseudo element `:before` or `:after` to any element in my page.

I have tried to use the "Named parameter" of LESS mixins to create a generic mixin in which the user could specify whether the pseudo element should be a `:before` or an `:after`.

When I compile, I get an error: "Unrecognized input".

Here is my code:

```
.setInlineIcon(@iconx: 0; @icony: 0; @pos: before; @margin: 0; @margindir: right) {
  &:@{pos} {
    .setStructure(@h: 16px; @w: 16px; @d: inline-block; @va: middle);
    .getIcon(@iconx; @icony);

    content:"";
    margin-@{margindir}: @margin;
  }
}
```

Where `.setStrucutre`and `.getIcon` are two already existing and functioning mixins. Can you spot what's wrong?

Is it because I cannot use a variable as a selector in this way?

Comment: Yes, this is known issue with current Less versions. `:` alone is not recognized as valid selector identifier. The workaround is to concat the `:` to a pseudo selector string before selector interpolation, e.g: `@name: ~':@{pos}'; &@{name} {...}`.

Comment: @seven-phases-max thanks a lot for your comment, your workaround worked! It seems I get the same issue with my margindir however, it only works if I comment the line out. Tried the same workaround but it wouldn't work.

Comment: `margin-@{margindir}: @margin;` is correct and should work fine provided that you use a compiler that actually supports this feature (Less or less.php >= 1.6.0).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I hadn't updated to the latest version, I was on LESS 1.5.x... :)

Comment: @seven-phases-max could you formulate your comments as an answer, please? so i can be accepted

Answer (score 7):

`:` alone is not recognized as valid selector identifier. The workaround is to concatenate it to the identifier before selector interpolation:

```
.mixin(@pos) {
    @name: ~':@{pos}';
    &@{name} {
        /* ... */
    }
}

usage {
    .mixin(before);
}
```

Comment: Nope, as far as I know (probably considered too rare to bother). I guess you can open an issue if you think it's important.